# The responsive menu messes everything up

Tags: html, css

I'm eating my head for days with this problem. I proposed to make a menu, two different menu lists, the language one and the section one. In normal size, I like how it looks, the problem comes when I make it responsive to look at how it looks and I don't know how to find a solution.

[image: In the first image: The normal result]
[image: In the second image: The current result]
[image: In the third image: Menu two, and I want the languages to appear above the home page]

I leave you the part of css and html.

```html
<header class="l-header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/espana (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="eu.html"><img src="img/pais-vasco (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="en.html"><img src="img/estados-unidos-de-america (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="fr.html"><img src="img/francia (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="de.html"><img src="img/alemania.png" alt=""></a>
        </li>

      </ul>


    </div>

    <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About me</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#skills" class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#work" class="nav__link">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#contact" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
      <em class='bx bx-menu'></em>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

```css
*=====NAV=====*/ .nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--header-height);
    right: 500%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
  .nav__menu1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--header-height);
    right: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
}

.nav__item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--second-color);
}

.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--second-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Active menu*/

.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=== Show menu ===*/

.show {
  right: 0;
}
```

can you help me.? Thanks a lot

After the code:
[image]

Comment: I guess there's some Javascript or jQuery missing that does the toggling of the menu (at least in the code you posted)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion.
Move the language content to the bottom of the nav when responsive and change it to a side-by-side view.

```html
<header class="l-header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div class="nav__menu nav__menu--lang" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list nav__list--lang">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/espana (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="eu.html"><img src="img/pais-vasco (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="en.html"><img src="img/estados-unidos-de-america (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="fr.html"><img src="img/francia (1).png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="de.html"><img src="img/alemania.png" alt=""></a>
        </li>

      </ul>


    </div>

    <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About me</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#skills" class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#work" class="nav__link">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#contact" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
      <em class='bx bx-menu'></em>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

```css
*=====NAV=====*/ .nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .l-header {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav__menu {
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
  .nav__menu--lang {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .nav__list--lang {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.nav__item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--second-color);
}

.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--second-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Active menu*/

.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=== Show menu ===*/

.show {
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! but again I have a problem. I have added a screenshot above again, after the code